# What is the name of that cool, embeddable faq/knowledge base service?

Tags: embed, disqus

Some time ago, I ran into a cool service which allows the user to manage a knowledge base or FAQ list. The knowledge base is easily embeddable on any site/CMS with a javascript, in a way similar to what Disqus does for commenting.

I can't for the life of me remember the name of this service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is the one you're referring to, but we have been looking into [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com), which can outsource feature requests, "Feedback", and "Helpdesk" for your site.

I like the fact that it resembles Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: Uservoice is most commonly used esp. in the way the OP mentioned

Comment: Uservoice is cool, but not what I had in mind. The thing I saw somewhere is a very simple knowledge base service.

Answer (score 0):

It could be ZenDesk, which seems to be popular right now. If not, scroll though http://alternativeto.net/software/zendesk/ and see if any of them ring a bell.